# Views Showing First Image only

Tags: views

I have a view that should show all the images. However, its only showing the first one. All images are set to publish and the sort criteria is set to ASC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide more details.

Comment: the content type i am using has 10 images that should show up in any view format that I set it as. Its only showing the first image however. Make sense?

Comment: looks like the only view format thats not working is the slideShow format

Comment: Ok, but without the export code or some screanshots I cann't suggest you solution for that.

Comment: turns out it was an issue with the slideShow views. i figured it out. thanks for looking tho.